# Changing .NET runtime at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, .net-runtime

We have an old .NET 3.5 application deployed out to multiple remote systems.  This application supports a plugin architecture that lets us download additional assemblies to the service whenever it starts up.  I'm trying to modify the application's app.config to add .NET 4.0 as a supportedRuntime to allow us to use plugin assemblies with a higher version than 3.5.  I'm checking registry keys and `Environment.Version` to see what's installed and what's currently supported before modifying the web.config as follows:

```
    private static bool EnableNet4Support()
    {
        try
        {
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            var startupSection = config.GetSection("startup");
            startupSection.SectionInformation.SetRawXml(@"
<startup><supportedRuntime version=""v4.0"" />
<supportedRuntime version=""v2.0.50727"" /></startup>");

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TraceHelper.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().ToString());
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This method is working fine when I test locally, but when I push to one of our test environments it doesn't work as expected.  The application can see .NET 4.8 is installed, so it makes the change to the web config.  Once I verify the config is updated correctly, I manually restart the service, or even shut down and start up.  When I do `Environment.Version` is still 2.0 even though the config suggests to use .NET 4.0 first.

These services are installed as a Windows Service, if that matters, and there wasn't a `<startup>` element in the config when I started.  I assume that just means the executing assembly gets to decide what to use, right?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 don't even use the same version of the CLR. If you start a .NET 3.5 app, it's going to use the CLR 2.0. Why not just upgrade everything to 4.8?

Comment: Right, that's the goal with changing the supportedRuntime config at runtime. We cannot do a full upgrade at this time as the number of remote machines numbers in the hundreds and we don't have an auto upgrade feature. There are plans for a large scale upgrade of this software in the future to .NET 8, but it requires careful planning and cannot be done right now. Like I said in my testing, when I do this locally, the supportedRuntime config is enough to convince the application to use the 4.0 runtime, just not when I deploy to a test environment.

Comment: .Net 4.8 is better supported than .Net 3.5 by now. 4.8 should be included by default in windows 10 from 2019+, while 3.5 require manual activation/installation on everything newer than win 7. And some bugs can make that installation fairly cumbersome. So if you keep all of these remove windows machines up to date you should not have any problems.

Comment: You shouldn't have to upgrade anything, if those machines run a supported version of Windows, they should already have .NET 4.6 or above installed.

Comment: I'm trying to get a .NET 3.5 application to run on the 4.0 runtime using a supportedRuntime element in the app.config, but it's not working.  Every time I check Environment.Version it tells me 2.0 regardless of what's in the app.config.  4+ is definitely installed.